# Problems authenticating with OneDrive for Business

Tags: onedrive

I'm testing out the OneDrive SDK .NET sample app [here](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-apibrowser-dotnet).  However it's unclear to me what values I need for the AadReturnUrl and AadTargetUrl constants which are used with the AdalAuthenticationProvider and OneDriveClient classes respectively.  The GitHub readme for the project refers to this [page](https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm), but that page isn't clear either.

Also: for a native client app, what value do you use for the the Redirect URI when you configure the app in Azure AD?  Is this value related to the required URLs above?

**Edit**: I tried the suggestion from the first comment and received the following error, from this code in FormBrowser.SignIn (where AadReturnURL = http://myactualdomain.onmicrosoft.com; this is a native app, and I assume this can be a 'dummy' URL if I don't have the means to display a web page):

```
var adalAuthProvider = new AdalAuthenticationProvider(FormBrowser.AadClientId, FormBrowser.AadReturnUrl);
this.oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient(FormBrowser.AadTargetUrl + "/_api/v2.0", adalAuthProvider);
authTask = adalAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync(FormBrowser.AadTargetUrl);
```

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Error: 4 : 10/24/2016 22:05:41: e9c2c5cd-1750-4d0f-b3a2-f373f7de309a - d__0: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS50001: The application named https://myactualdomain-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0 was not found in the tenant named myactualdomain.onmicrosoft.com.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Trace ID: 16192303-40e9-4944-b376-d25d4ff52b73
Correlation ID: e9c2c5cd-1750-4d0f-b3a2-f373f7de309a
Timestamp: 2016-10-24 22:05:40Z
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler.VerifyAuthorizationResult()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler.PreTokenRequest()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__0.MoveNext()
    ErrorCode: invalid_resource
    StatusCode: 0

OneDriveApiBrowser.vshost.exe Error: 0 : 10/24/2016 22:05:41: e9c2c5cd-1750-4d0f-b3a2-f373f7de309a - d__0: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS50001: The application named https://myactualdomain-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0 was not found in the tenant named myactualdomain.onmicrosoft.com.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Trace ID: 16192303-40e9-4944-b376-d25d4ff52b73
Correlation ID: e9c2c5cd-1750-4d0f-b3a2-f373f7de309a
Timestamp: 2016-10-24 22:05:40Z
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler.VerifyAuthorizationResult()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler.PreTokenRequest()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__0.MoveNext()
    ErrorCode: invalid_resource
    StatusCode: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AadTargetUrl` should be the URL of your service. For example, `https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/` would be the URL for your OneDrive for Business on the Contoso tenant. You can get more information about getting your target URL using the [Discovery Service](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm#step-3-discover-the-onedrive-for-business-resource-uri).

`AadReturnUrl` is the redirect URL you configured in the Azure Management Portal (as you correctly surmised). It's commonly something like `http://localhost:8080` for local apps, but could be something different for web apps. You can get more information about that in the [article you already linked](https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm#register-your-app-for-onedrive-for-business).

Comment: Thank you! Although I'm still unclear as to whether I can just use the URL you provided (minus Contoso of course), as it fails with a "not found" error (in my updated post). Otherwise, my review of the Discovery Service doc seems to imply that I actually have to develop a solution (or run the sample) to get the correct endpoint??

Comment: Also: does Graph need to be turned on for the OneDrive4B API and/or the Discovery Service?

Comment: I got it working, stupid mistake - my constant for AadTargetUrl was https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0, and of course the code I was calling was redundantly adding /_api/v2.0 to the URL